# What is the best way to navigate duplicate tag definitions in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, tags

Within emacs, what are the best options out there for navigating to a specific function whose name might show up across several different files?  Within etags, you are only allowed to cycle through the tags one-at-a-time which could take a while if the function name you are looking for is popular.

Answer (score 5):

*C-u M-.* cycles all locations of the same tag, but if you want to see a list of all tags that match your function name you can use the command *tags-apropos*.

Answer (score 3):

Etags-select:

http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/EtagsSelect

Answer (score 1):

If your programming language is **C** then [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) is much better than etags. It presents you with an interactive list of a symbol instances with its context. More info is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367/the-single-most-useful-emacs-feature#218611)

Answer (score 0):

1. [Icicles tag commands](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Emacs_Tags_Enhancements)

   In particular, use command `icicle-find-tag`,  to do what all of these vanilla commands do:

   - `find-tag` (<kbd>M-.</kbd>) to find a tag
   - `tags-loop-continue` (<kbd>M-,</kbd>) to find another matching tag
   - `tags-apropos` to list all tags that match a regexp
   - `list-tags` to show all tags (definitions) in a given source file.

   `icicle-find-tag` is a general tags browser: being a multicommand, you can visit any number of tags, in any order, in a single invocation.
2. [Icicles imenu](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Other_Search_Commands#IciclesImenu) -- Imenu across files or buffers. Search within selected function definitions (as the search contexts).